# C3P0 and Java Swing application

Tags: java, spring, swing, c3p0

I have an Java Swing application which include a c3p0 library for manage connection pools.
In its configuration I setted property c3p0.maxPoolSize=10 but it still creates more connections once a user logs in to the system.

```
c3p0.acquireIncrement=1
c3p0.minPoolSize=1
c3p0.maxPoolSize=10
c3p0.maxIdleTime=300
```

HOw can I control this behaviour?

Here is my Spring XML database config

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="main/resources/properties/database.properties" />
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${c3p0.acquireIncrement}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${c3p0.maxIdleTime}" />
</bean>
```

The bean is generated Ok, but I can't control this event:**when user logs in into the system c3p0 automatically opens three more connections.** What we want is **(1) "Tell" to c3p0 via XML config file that we want only db connection per user** and (2) **c3p0 please control the number of total database connections by setting the number of connections until 10...**

Please if I'm not clear, please tell me.

Comment: you'll need to provide a lot more information than this. when you set your configuration, where did you put it? did it "take", that is, when your c3p0 pool is initialized, do the parameters have the values you expect? (run your swing app from a command line and look at what gets logged, probably to standard error. c3p0's config will be dumped when the pool is started up). how are you managing authentication? note that c3p0 settings are on a per-authentication basis. if there is more than one db user, there will be more than one pool. acquireIncrement=1 is bad. try at least 3.

Comment: @SteveWaldman I'm using Spring as a framework. Properties showed in my are putted in a .properties file and it's passed to a XML for generate my bean in Spring

Comment: My problem is I set the maxpoolSize=10 why c3p0 don't respect this setting and still It creates three more connections per user who logs in into my system... please any questions or help is well received.

Comment: maxPoolSize is a per-db-user setting. each different db-authetication (user/password) gets its own pool with its own maxPoolSize. in most apps this isn't an issue: the DataSource is configured with a single authenticataion, and Conections are acquired with the no argument version of DataSource.getConnection(). it sounds like in your app you are letting different users provide their own credentials and calling getConnection(username,password). each credential set then is associated with its own pool of up to 10 Connections. there is no global cross-auth limit.

Comment: if you only want one db-connection per authentication credential, you don't want to use a Connection pool at all. the purpose of a Connection pool is to prefetch and maintain identical(ie same-auth) Connections so that clients don't experience the latency associated with acquiring a Connection directly from a database. (If you really want one connection per auth, you might consider eliminating the pool-related properties and switching the classname to "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource".)

Comment: Read carefully the comments by @SteveWaldman. Do I get it right, that you have multiple swing client instances on multiple machines, and you want to limit the total number of connections to your database (located on another server)?

Comment: @Bozho exactly. This Swing app plication is delivered to N users. I planned to set maximum number of connections and I thought that if c3p0 is used for web apps, why cannot be integrated in a Swing project.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Let me understand. Is a good practice just in case of Swing apps maintain only one connection per user? which is a good practice for this kind of project (not for web, just for client server enviroments)?

Comment: I thought c3p0 could manage all entire connections from the N users at the same time. Is it wrong, right?

Comment: Users logs in in a simple window with user-pwd fields... then between BO an DAO layers I validate this input and finally accept/deny session.

Comment: c3p0 PooledDataSources can manage Connections from arbitrary numbers of users, sure, but each user gets its own pool. That has to be the case -- a Connection pool must be a pool of interchangeable, identical resources, so that any Connection checked out from the pool is the same as any other. The pools live where the c3p0 DataSources live: if you are distributing an app with c3p0, then every instance of that app is likely creating their own pools. the database server knows nothing about c3p0.

Comment: c3p0 can only enforce limits on Connections within a pool. It can't enforce a global limit at the DBMS; configure your DBMS for that. c3p0 works as a resource manager for web apps because many clients to a web-app typically share the same JVM and so share the same pool. Limits set on that one pool instance effectively limit the use of all webapp clients. c3p0 will not work to limit resource usage by an app of which there might be arbitrarily many instances each with its own JVM and pool. You'd use c3p0 in a Swing! app to enhance performance, not to control server-side resource use.

Comment: If you want to limit database resource use by a Swing app (and DBMS settings aren't expressive enough), you'll probably need a middleware layer between the clients and the db. Swing clients would contact the middleware, where communication with the database would be centralized. In this architecture, a single c3p0 pool managed by the middleware (with just one db authentication credential) could be used to control DBMS resource use.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Thanks for yous help, Steve. Well explained and clearly effective. So now, can I exclude c3p0 library from my project right?

Answer (score 0):

I'll summarize the comments above:

- c3p0 (and any connection pool) is used for controlling the number of connections *of the client*
- If you want to limit the server connections, to that with a DB server configuration (e.g. for MySQL it's `max_connection`)
- You can still keep the connection pool on the client in order to optimize client-side performance - i.e. not opening a new connection every time it's needed.
- You should limit server-side connections only if there appears to be a problem. You risk having clients wait for connections (or worse - getting "Too many connections" errors) and being unable to use your software.